# jQuery empty validation for primefaces components

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I am wonder how to check by jQuery if there are some fields empty. If yes I'll show a dialog.

I was trying something like:

```
$('input:text').each(function( index ) {    
    if( $(this).val().length == 0){ 
         ...
    } 
});
```

Unfortunately I saw that for example for `<p:selectOneMenu>` value is always `""`, or what about `p:selectOneRadio`?

Answer (score 1):

Each component in PrimeFaces has it's own way to check if the value is empty or not.

Taking that in mind I'll post how to check for empty values in inputText, selectOneMenu, selectOneRadio in "almost" generic way.

```
for (var propertyName in PrimeFaces.widgets) {
   if (PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName] instanceof PrimeFaces.widget.InputText) {
      if(PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName].jq.val().length == 0) {
         PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName].jq.css('background', 'red')
      } 
    } else if(PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName] instanceof PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneRadio) {
      if(PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName].checkedRadio.length == 0){
         PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName].jq.css('background', 'red')
       }                                 
    } else if(PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName] instanceof  PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu) {
      if(PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName].getSelectedValue() == '') {
         PrimeFaces.widgets[propertyName].jq.parent().css('background', 'red')
      } 
    }
}
```

Basically we iterate over the widgets of PrimeFaces that we have in the page, and determine the way on how we check the value based on the component's type.

Now to extend this, you need to write every individual component's way of validation.

A small working example can be found on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/widgetsValidation/main.xhtml). And an [online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/widgetsValidation/main.xhtml).

Hope this helps.

Comment: what about for example <h:SelectOneMenu> ?

Comment: `<h:selectOneMenu>` is a normal HTML select, so `$('select').val() != ''` would do it. but this has to be done outside the scope of the for, it's completely different way of validation.

Comment: All in all it should be $('input:text').each(... val===0) $('select').each(... val===0) and thoose code with primefaces components ? Hmm wird but input:text also return items from p:selectOneMenu and thoos items are always "" ... -.-

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
$('input:text').each(function( index ) {    
     if( $(this).val().length == 0 || $.trim($(this).val()) == ""){ 
         alert("empty");
     } 
});
```

Comment: I got selectOneMenu with selected some item when I use on it $(this).val().length == 0 this is true. I dont know why I am getting always "" in selectOneMenu